# Compute $\int_C\textbf{F}\cdot ds$ for $\textbf{F}(x,y) = \frac{1}{x+y}\textbf{i}+\frac{1}{x+y}\textbf{j}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider the vector field

$\textbf{F}(x,y) = \frac{1}{x+y}\textbf{i}+\frac{1}{x+y}\textbf{j}$.

Compute the line integral $\int_C\textbf{F}\cdot ds$ where $C$ is the segment of the unit circle from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$.

My attempt:
I gather that since we're on the unit circle, we can parametrize as

$s = <\cos\theta,\sin\theta>$, so $ds = <-\sin\theta,\cos\theta>$, and

$\textbf{F}\cdot ds = \frac{\cos\theta-\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta} = \frac{1}{2}\cot\theta -\frac{1}{2}\tan\theta$, which evaluates as $0$ on $0\rightarrow\pi/2$, correct? I'm surprised this answer is zero, have I made a mistake?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can also see that if $f(x,y)=\log(x+y)$ then $F=\nabla f$ and then

$$\int_C F\cdot ds=f(0,1)-f(1,0)=\log(1)-\log(1)=0$$

So yes, the answer is right.